# Make Navbar stick at the top but when clicked on cross button in notification bar it should be removed and navbar stick to top:0

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When Clicked on cross button right to the notification bar it closes the notification and navbar moves to top, but I need both should stick to top and and behaviour should be same like when notification bar is closed navbar still its should stick to top.

[image: Notification and Navbar Image]

For Notification Bar code:

```
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
```

For Navbar code:

```
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 15px;
  position: sticky;
```

Comment: Please, provide full example of the HTML and CSS in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: To fix this issue, you just need to remove "top: 15px;" from css Navbar.

This is my demo:

```js
function closeNoti() { document.getElementById("noti").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: lightblue;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;  
}

.noti-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; 
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky; 
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 0;
}

.content p {
  padding: 20px 20px 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="noti-bar" id="noti">Notification Bar <span onclick="closeNoti()">X</span></div>
<div class="nav-bar">Nav Bar</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```